# ReporteController#opcionales is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["application/pdf"] request.variant: []

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, prawn, respond-to

"\nrequest.variant: #{request.variant.inspect}"

```
    raise ActionController::UnknownFormat, message
  elsif interactive_browser_request?
    message = "#{self.class.name}\##{action_name} is missing a template " \
      "for this request format and variant.\n\n" \
```

My controller

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    pdf = Prawn::Document.new
    params[:id] = @ids
    @opcionales = Opcionale.where("id= ?", @ids)
    ...
    send_data pdf.render, filename: "Reporte_#{@opcionales}.pdf",
                        type: "application/pdf",
                        disposition: "inline"

  end
end
```

My routes

get 'reporte/opcionales'

get 'reporte/opcionales/:id', to: "reporte#opcionales", :defaults => { :format => 'pdf' }

In my views

{<%= link_to "Generar PDF", '/reporte/opcionales/'+(opcionales.id.to_s)+'.pdf' %>}

Comment: This answer in another SO post might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61871663/3287738

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `config/intializers/mime_types.rb` and add `Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf` and then install the gem responders