# How to preview pdf using active storage and poppler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, preview, rails-activestorage, poppler

I'm trying to display a preview of the uploaded pdf in my application but all I get so far is a broken image.

I have installed the poppler gem as suggested in the active storage presentation for preview.

Then i tried different ways but all are returning a broken image.

```
<%= link_to bank.rib, rails_blob_path(bank.rib, disposition: "preview") %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag bank.rib %>
```

or

where '`rib`' being the attached file (`has_one`) of the model **BankAccount** (here `bank = BankAccount.find(id)`)

`bank.rib.previewable?` returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Installing poppler, is just one of the steps you might need, here are some other things you should check:

1. Rails might be requiring some additional gems installed:

> You must have ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick installed

Add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
```

and install imagemagick:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

2. Another possible issue is that your application cannot reach the **/rails/active_storage** path, so verify the path is mounted or you do not have a catch_all route that overwrites that path, in case you do, you can exclude rails path with the following:

`get "*unmatched_route", constraints: -> (req) { !(req.fullpath =~ /^\/rails\/(active_storage|conductor|action_mailbox)\/.*/) }`